# Assignment of two values in parentheses in C

Tags: c, syntax

What does this piece of code in C do:

```
p = (1, 2.1);
```

What do we know about `p`?

Comment: "What do we know about p?" sounds like a homework question

Comment: I know it's your first question, and it's a good question, but most people here seem to prefer that questions not have greetings. It's no big deal, though. Also, the site has some formatting capability that you can use to make your code look nicer. I went ahead and fixed it up for you - I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Glen, it sounds more like deeply philosophical question to me.

Comment: Just because of the wording to add "homework" sounds odd.

Answer (score 20):

The comma operator in C is a *sequence point* which means that the expressions separated by the comma are executed from left to right. The *value* of the whole expression is the value of the rightmost expression, in your case `2.1`, which gets assigned to the variable `p`.

Since the expressions in your example don’t have side effects, the use of the comma separator here makes no sense whatsoever.

The parentheses on the other hand are important since the assignment operator (`=`) binds stronger than the comma operator (it has higher precedence) and would get evaluated *before* the comma operator without the parentheses. The result would thus be `p == 1`.

Comment: In twenty years of writing C code, I have yet to find a really useful non-hackish use for the comma operator.

Comment: You can overload the operator in C++ (but not C, obviously) and Boost makes some beautiful use of that to implement list initializations, such as `list_type mylist = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Comment: @Graeme, i bet you sometimes found `for(i = 0; i < n; i++, j--) ...;` to be useful

Comment: @Graeme Perrow -- most of the time I use it is in a for() statement, as in for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < whatever; i++, j++ )... and I end up asking myself "what have I done wrong here" then end up fixing it.

Comment: @litb Yes, I have done that, but I always wince a little as I type it. Unless it's temporary throw-away code, I usually try to find a different way of doing it. That usage would fall under the "hackish" category. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: Most plausible case for a comma operator in the continuation statement is maybe: `int index = 0; for (node *p = head->next; p != tail; p = p->next, ++index) { something }`

Comment: Graeme, why would you want non-hackish use if there're plenty of hackish ones?

Comment: The comma operator is a hackish operator pretty much by definition -it's to hack in 2 things where only one is allowed.

Comment: Michael, so are compounds ;-)

Comment: `if (p = malloc(…), p == NULL)` is nicer to read than `if ((p = malloc()) == NULL)`

Comment: why not `if( p = malloc( ... ) )`? I usually use `if( ! (p = malloc( ... )) ) return 0;`

Comment: Carson Myers, because there's no comma in it! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake. the comma operator is similar to ;. It does the one, then the other. so (1,2.1) evaluates to 2.1

p will be 2.1 (or 2, if p is an int and needs to be truncated...)

Comment: It's not necessarily a mistake, just totally useless.

Comment: uhuh. How often have you seen that functionality and it NOT be a mistake? yes, it couldbe, but HIGHLY unlikely, no?

Comment: I've seen it once: Here, and it's used as a homework exercise to test knowledge about the comma operator. So far, based on all the cases I've seen, use of the comma operator in this way is not a mistake 100% of the time.

Comment: 99% of the time I've seen it (in CS 1 projects, etc) is people failing to do 2D arrays... arr[3,5] != arr[3][5]...

Answer (score 0):

all comma seprated expressions will be evaluated from left to right and value of rightmost expression will be returned.

so p will 2.1.